# Typescript: How can I reference another document's field inside of this document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm currently learing TS, and I re-write my old NodeJS/Express project. I need to reference another document's field in the validator, but I recieve an error:

> Property 'price' does not exist on type '{ validator: (val: number) => boolean; }'.ts(2339).

Here's the code:

```
const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, ' A tour must have a price']
  },
  priceDiscount: {
    validator: function(val: number): boolean {
      return val < this.price
    },
    message: 'Discount price ({VALUE}) should be below regular price'
  }
});
```

[Here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNXBk.png)

As you can see I need priceDiscount validator, but I can't reference another field in the document, because TS doesn't know if this field exists. How can I make it to know, that I want to reference another field on the same document?

Comment: maybe this helps u https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know the specifics of how mongoose works, but if that code is correct, the issue is that the validator function has its `this` bound to something other than the default.

You can annotate the function explicitly to tell TS [the type of `this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters), e.g.

```
validator: function(this: { price: number }, val: number): boolean {
  return val < this.price
},
```

Comment: Unfortunately tihs won't work, becase validator function recieves only one argument.

Comment: @Craig: That will not be interpreted as an additional argument. It merely adds a type to `this`.

Comment: It worked! I also read the documentation. I haven't known it works this way, thank you. I just thought we are passing this as argument. Thank you! 

Also, maybe you can tell me, I wonder why this code: this: { price: number } works the way it works. I know TS accepts it and sees that "this" must be a an object with property price which is a string. But shouldn't it expect "this" to be an object with ONLY property price which is a string?

Comment: @Craig: I do not quite understand your question. If you type `this` like that it should only register as having the `price` property (which is a `number`, you wrote string twice, though?).

Comment: Sorry I mistyped, I meant number not string.

And what I meant was, I understand the syntax: this: { price: number } as telling TS that object "this" will have a property price, and this property will be a number. Although in fact we know, that "this" will have some other properties, not only the price. And this confuses me, because if we made a type like this: let foo: {price: number}, we would tell TS that foo must be an obj with ONLY the price property. And I wonder why it works this way.

Comment: @Craig TS does not know what the actual type of the argument will be in this case and for function arguments the only thing that matters is that the passed object has the expected properties. It simply does not matter if the passed in object has any other properties. That is the point of interfaces in general: To specify what is required and the implementation details of what else is on an object is irrelevant. Does that help?

Comment: Right, but when we declare an interafce like this: interface foo {name: string}, then every object that will recieve interface foo as a type, will expect only name property. So I just need to assume, that in terms of function arguments it behaves in this different way? Similar to classes, when you define a class that implements an interface, then you need to specify properties from interface, but you can also specify some other properties/methods.

Btw. thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, I've made a mistake in a code above. The proper code, with the solution of @H.B is:

```
const tourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, ' A tour must have a price']
  },
  priceDiscount: {
    type: Number,
    validate: {
      validator: function(this: { price: number }, val: number): boolean {
        return val < this.price;
      }
    },
    message: 'Discount price ({VALUE}) should be below regular price'
  }
});
```